# Was Columbia University fined for animal cruelty due to experiments run by Mehmet Oz?

Tags: united-states, medical-science, animal-welfare, mehmet-oz

This [SourceWatch article](https://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php/Columbia_University#Animal_cruelty_.26_welfare_violations) is being publicized in connection to Mehmet Oz:

> In 2004, complaints about Dr. Mehmet Oz’s dog experiments were cited in a report from an internal investigation into allegations of poor animal care made by Dr. Catherine Dell’Orto, a post-doctoral veterinarian. [5], [6] See also individual reports of Dr. Oz's dog experiments. [7] According to the report, "highly invasive and stressful experiments" on dogs were performed without a "humane end point." AWA violations included a litter of whelped puppies killed by painful cardiac injection:
>
> > "The screams of these puppies could be heard through closed doors. All of these puppies, lying in a plastic garbage bag, were killed in the presence of their litter mates."[8]
>
> Subsequent applications for grants to the National Institutes of Health (NIH) by Dr. Oz have been denied.[9] In 2004, Columbia paid $2,000 in fines to the USDA. [10]

However, all of the reference citations point to ColumbiaCruelty.com and StopAnimalTests.com, both of which were run by the animal rights group PETA and (more importantly) no longer exist.

I found [one independent reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1087195/) to animal cruelty at Columbia University in the early 2000s, but it doesn't involve Dr Oz.

Comment: The last link again mentions an *internal* investigation, saying "... was ordered by the university in early 2003, and has thus far found no evidence of any significant violations of conduct. "

Comment: The linked SourceWatch article's references lead to [Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090218192828/http://www.columbiacruelty.com/feat-pupkillings.asp) and further describes the events, giving a link to a [USDA document](https://web.archive.org/web/20090218192828/http://www.columbiacruelty.com/letters/USDA.pdf), which shows a fine of $2000 and is dated 2004 (concerning events in 2003).

Comment: The title asks two questions. Are you asking if the uni was fined for cruelty, or asking if the experiments were run by Dr Oz?

Comment: The question is about cruelty linked to [Oz's lab](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22MC+Oz%22+Columbia+University), whether conducted by himself or subordinates.